# Sum/consolidate/combine reversed pairs in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which is something like this with counts of paired relationships with the pair often in reversed order.

```
country1    country2    count
 CHN         KOR         65
 TWN         KOR         32
 KOR         CHN         43
```

Here I have CHN - KOR and KOR - CHN. If I have already determined that these are distinct counts then these just represent two ways of describing a relationship and I would like to sum the counts of the pair so the final result is

```
country1    country2    count
 CHN         KOR         108
 TWN         KOR          32
```

I'm using Big Query. Does anyone know of a way of consolidating reversed pairs in SQL? Note: These are not duplicates, so this is not a question of removing duplicates, but combining reversed pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select country1, country2, sum(count)
from ((select country1, country2, count
       from t
       where country1 <= country2
      ) union all
      (select country2, country1, count
       from t
       where country1 > country2
      )
     ) cc
group by country1, country2;
```

This will work for both the legacy and standard interface.  For the standard, BigQuery supports `greatest()` and `least()` on strings:

```
select least(country1, country2), greatest(country1, country2), sum(count)
from ((select country1, country2, count
       from t
       where country1 <= country2
      ) union all
      (select country2, country1, count
       from t
       where country1 > country2
      )
     ) cc
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Just one small correction: BigQuery Standard SQL doesn't allow expressions in GROUP BY, so your solution ought to be corrected to say "group by 1, 2" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, to show power and coolness of BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(country ORDER BY country) 
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[country1, country2]) AS country
    ) AS countries,
    SUM(COUNT) AS COUNT
  FROM yourTable 
  GROUP BY countries
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(countries, r'(\w+),') AS country1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(countries, r',(\w+)') AS country2,
  COUNT
FROM pairs
```

This version can be far more optimal when you have more than just two fields that are "mis-ordered"

You can briefly test it with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
SELECT 'CHN' AS country1, 'KOR' AS country2, 65 AS COUNT UNION ALL
SELECT 'TWN', 'KOR', 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KOR', 'CHN', 43 
)
```

And below is quick example of case when more than two fields are shuffled

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
SELECT 'CHN' AS country1, 'KOR' AS country2, 'US' as country3, 65 AS COUNT UNION ALL
SELECT 'TWN', 'KOR', 'GB', 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KOR', 'US', 'CHN', 43 
),
pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(country ORDER BY country) 
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[country1, country2, country3]) AS country
    ) AS countries,
    SUM(COUNT) AS COUNT
  FROM yourTable 
  GROUP BY countries
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(countries, r'(\w+),\w+,\w+') AS country1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(countries, r'\w+,(\w+),\w+') AS country2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(countries, r'\w+,\w+,(\w+)') AS country3,
  COUNT
FROM pairs
```

Sure, can be further optimized, but the main focus here on logic of reshuffling that does not require multiple comparisons/etc

> Addition

Thank you @GordonLinoff for insisting on below option! I think you are right  - it is more elegant to use ARRAY_AGG here

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
SELECT 'CHN' AS country1, 'KOR' AS country2, 'US' AS country3, 65 AS count UNION ALL
SELECT 'TWN', 'KOR', 'GB', 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KOR', 'US', 'CHN', 43 
),
pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(country ORDER BY country) 
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[country1, country2, country3]) AS country
    ) AS countries,
    count
  FROM yourTable 
)
SELECT 
  countries[OFFSET(0)] AS country1,
  countries[OFFSET(1)] AS country2,
  countries[OFFSET(2)] AS country3,
  SUM(count) AS count
FROM pairs
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Why would you `string_agg()` instead of `array_agg()` and just pull out the elements?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you can try this too. just wanted to give direction different from classic/obvious ones given in other answers. you can upvote this if you like it :o)

Comment: I would upvote if you used arrays.  Using a string to represent the list instead of arrays is less general and just inelegant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - have you tried using array_agg in this particular case? it just makes it heavier and even less elegant. :o) try - and you will see. but still - this was not a goal to use array_agg but rather was goal to give really working solution that is different from others

Comment: @GordonLinoff - on second thought - looks like you are right and version with ARRAY_AGG more suited here and sexier. Thank you for pushing me to this version :o)  see my update